# Compare return of count from sql query in python/databricks?

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I would like to return the sql count result and if the count is greater than 0 I would like to induce a fail func.

However, I am getting an error. I assume this is because the id_of_zero_count is a string and it cannot be compared against an integer?

```
id_of_zero_count = sql(""" SELECT count(*) cnt FROM schema.table where ID = 0 """.format(val))
#BU.collect[0][0] returns the value of the first row & first column

display(id_of_zero_count)

if id_of_zero_count > 0:
  print("Quality check not passed")
  induce_fail_func()
```

This is the error that is returned:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'DataFrame' and 'int'

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-873419207778593> in <module>
----> 1 if id_of_zero_count > 0:
      2   print("Quality check not passed")
      3   induce_fail_func()

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'DataFrame' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 1):

The sql query returns a dataframe, you should see that in your display call.

You can get the first element of the first row instead:

```
if id_of_zero_count.first()[0] > 0:
  print("Quality check not passed")
  induce_fail_func()
```

Comment: It returns TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable